# What kind of heaters are used for heated floor panels?

Tags: airbus

In some Airbus planes, they have heated floor panels. So, what kind of heaters are being used there?

Comment: The warm air from the AC through a cavity would be cheapest, lightest and safest.

Comment: Do you mean the cabin is fully heated by devices in the floor, or just heaters at the doors ([to prevent icing](http://www.erieaviation.com/floorpanels.htm) - Also used in flight decks). Can you provide a reference to an aircraft model?

Comment: Related: [Patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US8371526) transferred from Goodrich to Airbus.

Answer (score 1):

Electrical, connected to one of the AC buses. [This is an example](http://www.goodrich.com/cap/systems/sisdocuments/Ice%20Detection%20and%20Protection%20Systems/Heated%20Floor%20Panels.pdf), absorbing 620 watts/m^2.